# ActiveRecord::Relation returning different class object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 4.2 webapp. It has the typical `User` model based off `Devise` for people to sign up, log in, and do their thing.

At the same time, i have another model called `Partner` and it is connected to a remote database called `Partner_Data` containing a table called '`user`'.

In my rails console, i am getting an object of the `User` class when it should be Partner. Any ideas on what's happening?

```
> abc_partner = Partner.where(id:200)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 262, email: "abc@abc.xyz", created_at: ...>]>
> abc_partner.class
=> Partner::ActiveRecord_Relation
> abc_partner.first.class
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string ... )
```

A temporary fix i've done is

```
abc_partner.becomes(Partner)
=> #<Partner id:262 name: 'John Doe', partners_since:'2013-03-19', location:'New York, NY', company:'ABCD Corp.'>
```

HOWEVER: i also have an `Asset` model that's also connected to the same remote database, using a table of the same name '`asset`' and i get back something that works:

```
> abc_asset = Asset.where(id:101)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Asset id: 213, name: "arc", description: "My arc", created_at: "2015-03-13", owner_login: "John Doe", ...>]>
> abc_asset.class
=> Asset::ActiveRecord_Relation
> abc_asset.first.class
=> Asset(id: integer, name: string, description: text, created_at: datetime, ...)
```

I've experimented by changing the name '`user`' table of `Partners_Data` database to various things like '`partner_user`' or '`omg_user`' to see if table name made a difference, and nothing changed.

I notice that abc_partner.class and abc_asset both return something different..., Partner::ActiveRecord_Relation and Asset::ActiveRecord_Relation...

Classes:

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:my_partners_db)
  self.table_name = 'user'

  belongs_to: :partner_list
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:my_partners_db)
  self.table_name = 'asset'

end
```

Over in `database.yml`:

```
my_partners_db:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  host: 1.1.1.1
  database: partner_data
  username: some_username
  password: some_password
  pool: 7
  port: 3317
```

Comment: Can you please show at least your Partner model and how are you making a connection to a separate database.

Comment: Post has been updated to include the classes

Comment: Really interesting question, unless anyone solves this during the day I look forward to researching this when I get of work.

Comment: I tried this out a little bit. I can not reproduce these results. for me your code works without any trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with the fact that you have

`self.table_name = 'user'`

in your `Partner` model? docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name)

If what you're trying to do is make `Partner` is a type of `User`, then consider ActiveRecord [inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).